# I wonder how to put the parameters in nn.LSTM in this situation

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, forecasting

I want to say that I'm not familiar with English.

Hi, I'm recently building LSTM Layers using ***nn.LSTM***.

What I want to do is predicting next 48 values using 48*7=336 sequential inputs.
And here is preprocessed dataframe will be used. It has 384 cols(=336+48) and 457068 rows(=929x492).
In short, there are 929 customers and each customers has 492 sequential data with a length of 384(=336+48)

| customerID | col1 | col2 | ... | col380 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | data_{1,1} | data_{1,2} | ... | data_{1,380} |
| 1 | data_{2,1} | data_{2,2} | ... | data_{2,380} |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1 | data_{492,1} | data_{492,2} | ... | data_{492,380} |
| 2 | data_{493,1} | data_{493,2} | ... | data_{493,380} |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 929 | data_{4670687,1} | data_{4670687,2} | ... | data_{4670687,380} |
| 929 | data_{4670688,1} | data_{4670688,2} | ... | data_{4670688,380} |

Here, 3 parameters for nn.LSTM : (input_size, hidden_size, num_layers)
Also Input tensor has 3 dimensions : (seq_len, batch, input_size)\

In this situation, please let me know how to enter the above parameters. I will use **num_layers=2**.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the 3 parameters for the LSTM, `input_size` will be the same as input_size in your input tensor, which here is **336**.

`hidden_size` could be any number you want, it is basically the number of nodes or features you want to learn. The higher the number the more the model learns about your data at each training iteration. It mostly depends on how tough your task is for your model, though you would not want this to be unnecessarily large.

Since you have chosen `num_layers=2` you can define the LSTM like this:

```
# Using hidden_size=256, which could be any number you want
nn.LSTM(input_size=336, hidden_size=256, num_layers=2)
```

Comment: Thank u so much:) My model is learning using parameters you gave!

Comment: @HSR You're welcome. You can accept my answer if it answers your question.